# ng-file-upload issue on IE9 - after uploading one file receiving error

Tags: ng-file-upload

```
var prevFiles = ((ngModel && ngModel.$modelValue) || attr.$$ngfPrevFiles || []).slice(0);
```

I am getting an error that the result of this statement does not have a slice method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing too much about the module I have a theory:

The first evaluation `(ngModel && ngModel.$modelValue)`, when true, returns a Boolean which does not have a slice method.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue filed in Github about this https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1139

Reportedly fixed in release 10.0.3.